# Inspect With JarSpy not working in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I am new to Intellij IDEA.  I have installed jarSpy plugin on Intellij IDEA from the plugin repository.  However, when I was trying to view the content of a jar (ex. gradle-wrapper.jar) by right clicking on it and selecting "Inspect With JarSpy", nothing has happened.  What else should I do to view the jar content ?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you on? Assuming you got this one, the plugin could very well be incompatible with newer versions of IntelliJ because it's so old: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11?pr=idea  You could use something like 7Zip to go through jars. Let me know if this interests you, and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response.  The version of IDEA I am using is 14.1.4.  Thanks.

Comment: yes, I think I got the version 1.0 of the jarSpy.  I found it from the Settings-->plugin

Comment: In that case, I think it is safe to assume that the plugin might not support IntelliJ 14 because it hasn't been updated in over a decade. What did you need the plugin for? What functionality do you want?

Comment: I want to be able to look at the classes contained in a jar file, similar to what jarPlug does in Eclipse.

Comment: You can do this directly from IntelliJ in the project structure if you have added the jar to your project. You just need to click it and it will expand like a package. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind, I'll add it as an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 1):

[JarSpy](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11?pr=idea) hasn't been updated for over a decade, so it is very possible that it is not compatible with IntelliJ 14. But since your goal is just to browse through the classes in a jar, you can do this straight from IntelliJ if you have [added the jar to your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project). You can just click it in the project structure and it will expand like a package.